# Soundcloud Streaming audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundcloud, soundmanager2

I am trying to stream a track from soundcloud user. I have the client id and pulling the tracks works fine. But when I try to play a track, it's not working . This is the code that I use in `onload()` of my webpage.

```
<script>
    function pageload()
    { 
        SC.initialize({
            client_id: {MY CLIENT ID}
        });

        SC.stream("/tracks/{MY TRACK ID}", function(sound){
            sound.play();
        });
    }
</script>
```

NOTE: I have included soundmanagerjs too.

And in console I get an error.

```
[23:38:44.140] -- SoundManager 2: HTML5 support tests (/^(probably|maybe)$/i): mp3: false (using flash), mp4: false (using flash), ogg: true, wav: true 
[23:38:44.199] sound.play is not a function
```

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more code? I.e. where you are initializing SoundManager?

Comment: Just to make sure it's not a browser problem, is this working for you? http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14333604/demos/sdk.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a javascript error, not soundmanager.

```
function(sound){
        sound.play();
});
```

This is your problem, in that you're calling a nonexistant function. I'm not too sure what your other code is, but generally the way you play sounds in soundmanager is:

```
soundManager.play(SoundID);
```

I would assume in your case that the variable 'sound' you pass is the soundid, so in function(sound) put

```
soundManager.play(sound);
```